# How to add image at right bottom div using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently use this tab using bootstrap v3.3.4...
CSS:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #92278f;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #92278f;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: #92278f;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    border-image: none;
}
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #92278f;
}
```

DOM:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#parent" data-toggle="tab">Parent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#student" data-toggle="tab">Student</a></li>
</ul>
```

My current output:

[image]

How I can add this image:

[image]

at the bottom and become like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your markup to match it with bootstrap's. I am adding the image to the content panels instead of the `ul.nav-tabs`

Requires no additional markup for the image. Done using pseudo element `:after`.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Loading custom CSS after bootstrap's -->
<style>
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #92278f;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #92278f;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: #92278f;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    border-image: none;
  }
  .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #92278f;
  }
  /*THE CHANGES I MADE*/
  .tab-pane {
    position: relative;
  }
  .tab-pane:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 41px;
    height: 23px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYs3f.png);
    right: 0;
  }
</style>

<div role="tabpanel">
  <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#parent" data-toggle="tab">Parent</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#student" data-toggle="tab">Student</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="parent">Parent Tab Content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="student">Student Tab Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS only solution.**

You can not make modifications to the unordered list(`ul`'s) bottom border. Instead add a div under the tabs and add the triangle before it.

```css
/*to make the triange*/
.row:before {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 41px 23px 0; /*width and height*/
  border-color: transparent #92278F transparent transparent;
}

/*chnage active tab color and bottom border*/
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #92278F !important;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #92278F !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#parent" data-toggle="tab">Parent</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#student" data-toggle="tab">Student</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is using pure css, I have used no images. this will save more bandwidth as compared to using images. I have modified the snippet to exactly match the needed result.

Comment: Thanks for your effort...sometimes I will replace the image to other image soon or later...

Answer (score 0):

1.set the parent element's of the ul as 'position:relative'
2.add a new div as a sibling of the ul as  'position:absolute;background:the image url'
3.adjust the 'top' and 'right' of the image div in css accordingly

```
<div style="position: relative">    
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#parent" data-toggle="tab">Parent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#student" data-toggle="tab">Student</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="position: absolute;background:(imageurl);top:10px;right:0px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you should change the imageurl and the value of top and right yourself.

Comment: Instead of using another div, how I can exactly use css to put the image?